# Push Notification on iOS

Tags: android, iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm pretty new to iOS development, and was just wondering is it possible to activate your iOS application with a Push Notification.

On Android it is possible to use services for background work, but with iOS, unfortunately you can't, I know some things work, like VoIP, but that would be rejected by Apple, as far as I know, but what I mean is could I make my iOS application do just a little bit of work for like 30 seconds or so, every so often, via Push Notifications?

PS: I know Push Notification is for advanced users, but I want to know if the above is possible otherwise I will have to scrap my idea =[

Thanks.

Comment: What version of iOS are you targeting? Have you read the associated docs / watched the WWDC videos?

Comment: Well, any versions of iOS, 5+, I think.. I haven't been at it in a while since I found out that there was no background work (services) in iOS. I have read some tutorials on how to use/set-up Push Notifications. But at the moment I'm only thinking/researching.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can push notifications be used to run code without notifying user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861117/can-push-notifications-be-used-to-run-code-without-notifying-user)

Comment: Yes, that is a duplicate, thank you guys very much, I just didn't know how to put it into search words.. xD

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 can. Check out WWDC Videos. Also I wouldn't support iOS 5+ stick with either just 7 or if you really have to 6/7